# Can't open program because of int main error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I know it is duplicated... I didn't understand any of the other threads. Literally just started to learn programming. Currently trying to learn C++ as my first language. Ran into this error, I did google it but I didn't really know what they were talking about. I looked at both of my "int main" things and they are exactly the same. No errors. I guess formatted wrong. Here is the code. I'm currently playing around with the std::count and variables, along with std:cin

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, how are you doing? I suppose you are only here to read this. Oh well.";
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please feed me a number: " << "It can be any number."; // Asking human to enter a number.
    int x{ }; // get number from keyboard and store it in value x
    std::cin >> x; // recieved number and is now entering console
    std::cout << "Thank you for feeding me " << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I properly embed my code into the thread? I see that it is very clungy right now.

Comment: Nice one :) You're only allowed to have **one** main function.

Comment: What is the error? You can't put 2 main functions in a single file.

Comment: the error is int main(void)' already has a body
: note: see previous definition of 'main'   btw, what do I replace with main then?

Comment: If you want to create a new program, you have to create a *new* program, source files and all. You can't have multiple programs in a single "program". More specifically, you can only define a symbol (like `main`) *once* in a single program.

Comment: Don't try to learn `c++` by guessing and experimenting. Get your hands on a good book or tutorial to ger you started.

Comment: Oh no, this is all meant to show up in one program. I want to publish the program and see what it looks like, but it gives me this error.

Comment: please fix your title, the title should be a brief summary of the problem/question. And btw you dont want help from unexperienced people?, kinda discriminatory :P

Comment: When learning C++, you might want to follow a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: "I know it is duplicated... " when you already found duplicates then you should explain why they didnt help and what exactly is missing for you to understand, otherwise you will just get the same answers ...or get flagged as duplicate

Answer (score -1):

A C++ program need only one `main()` function. This latter is called at program startup. Your code should look like this :

```
#include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
  std::cout << "Hello, how are you doing? I suppose you are only here to read this. Oh well." << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Please feed me a number: " << " It can be any number." << std::endl; // Asking human to enter a number.
  int x{ }; // get number from keyboard and store it in value x
  std::cin >> x; // recieved number and is now entering console
  std::cout << "Thank you for feeding me " << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
 }
```

Here a [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) for more reading about the `main()` function.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I removed an int main and a return 0 along with a "{" Let's see if it works.

Comment: It worked. It looks very sloppy though and all of the words are together. Will have to work on that. Haha, would be interesting to write a book in one program using this language.

Comment: As suggested in the comment above, try to change the question so it describes the problem. Now you can accept the answer.

Comment: @datagen If this answers your question, click the green tick on the left to mark your problem as solved.